# How do I introspect an object?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find out whether the content of an object has been created and what the contents are.

I thought pprint would do it but all if get is:

```
<svgwrite.drawing.Drawing at 0x11059d978>
```

This is what is producing the object:

```python
import svgwrite as svgw
from IPython.display import SVG, display
import pprint

### Create header line in an SVG object
dwg = svgw.Drawing(filename='header_line.svg', debug=True)
header_line = dwg.add(dwg.line(id='hline', stroke='black', start=(100,0), end=(900,0)))
pprint.pprint(dwg)
```

Comment: Is `vars(dwg)` what you're after? Also, if you're using ipython, you can suffix objects with `?` or `??` to get extra information.

Comment: You can accomplish this by debugging your script in an IDE (like pycharm) and setting a breakpoint at the line you want to stop

Comment: Am using Jupyter Notebook. - Thanks!